# Query to find difference and displaying only those record whose difference is less than zero

Tags: mysql

I am having problem in finding some records in MySql using the following query

```
select 
dletterdate,
days,
date_add(dletterdate,interval days day) as added ,
now() as todaysdate, datediff(now(),date_add(dletterdate,interval days day)) as difference  
from mandereports
```

Actually i want to display only those records whose difference is less than zero. This is screenshot of the output:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` clause.

```
select 
    dletterdate,
    days,
    date_add(dletterdate,interval days day) as added ,
    now() as todaysdate, datediff(now(),date_add(dletterdate,interval days day)) as difference  
    from mandereports
    where difference < 0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was writing where clause before from clause :-;